# gatling checking if soap response contains node

Tags: gatling

I use Gatling to test against an API responding with this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <sam:HentAktiveSamtykkerMedPartrefResponse xmlns:sam="urn:gjensidige:forsikring:samtykke">
            <sam:samtykke>
                <sam:idNr>01018448285</sam:idNr>
                <sam:partref>0005009147</sam:partref>
                <sam:utfortAv></sam:utfortAv>
                <sam:navn></sam:navn>
                <sam:navnUtvidet></sam:navnUtvidet>
                <sam:svar>J</sam:svar>
```

How can I script that the response must contain the element:

```
<sam:svar>
```

?

I guess something in the lines of:

```
.check(xpath("whathere").exists)
```

But what should be stated as "whathere"?

Answer (score 0):

The xpath would look something like : `/*/SOAP-ENV:Body/descendant::*[name()='sam:navn']/text()` this should extract the value from `<sam:navn></sam:navn>`.